# Remove some main commands and/or default options from waf in wscript

Tags: waf

I have a waf script which adds some options, therefore I use `Options` from the `waflib`.

A minimal working example is:

```py
from waflib import Context, Options
from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load('compiler_c')
    cnf.env.abc = 'def'

def build(bld):
     print('hello')
```

Which lead to a lot of options I do not support, but others I would like to or have to support. The full list of default support commands is shown below. But how do I remove the options that are actually not supported like

- some main commands, like e.g., `dist`, `step` and `install` or
- some options like e.g., `--no-msvs-lazy` or
- some Configuration options like e.g., `-t` or
- **completely** the whole section `Installation and uninstallation options`

The full ouput of options is then:

```
waf [commands] [options]

Main commands (example: ./waf build -j4)
build    : executes the build
clean    : cleans the project
configure: configures the project
dist     : makes a tarball for redistributing the sources
distcheck: checks if the project compiles (tarball from 'dist')
distclean: removes build folders and data
install  : installs the targets on the system
list     : lists the targets to execute
step     : executes tasks in a step-by-step fashion, for debugging
uninstall: removes the targets installed

Options:
--version             show program's version number and exit
-c COLORS, --color=COLORS
                        whether to use colors (yes/no/auto) [default: auto]
-j JOBS, --jobs=JOBS  amount of parallel jobs (8)
-k, --keep            continue despite errors (-kk to try harder)
-v, --verbose         verbosity level -v -vv or -vvv [default: 0]
--zones=ZONES         debugging zones (task_gen, deps, tasks, etc)
-h, --help            show this help message and exit
--msvc_version=MSVC_VERSION
                        msvc version, eg: "msvc 10.0,msvc 9.0"
--msvc_targets=MSVC_TARGETS
                        msvc targets, eg: "x64,arm"
--no-msvc-lazy        lazily check msvc target environments

Configuration options:
    -o OUT, --out=OUT   build dir for the project
    -t TOP, --top=TOP   src dir for the project
    --prefix=PREFIX     installation prefix [default: 'C:\\users\\user\\appdata\\local\\temp']
    --bindir=BINDIR     bindir
    --libdir=LIBDIR     libdir
    --check-c-compiler=CHECK_C_COMPILER
                        list of C compilers to try [msvc gcc clang]

Build and installation options:
    -p, --progress      -p: progress bar; -pp: ide output
    --targets=TARGETS   task generators, e.g. "target1,target2"

Step options:
    --files=FILES       files to process, by regexp, e.g. "*/main.c,*/test/main.o"

Installation and uninstallation options:
    --destdir=DESTDIR   installation root [default: '']
    -f, --force         force file installation
    --distcheck-args=ARGS
                        arguments to pass to distcheck
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For options, The option context has a `parser` attribute which is a python `optparse.OptionParser`. You can use the `remove_option` method of `OptionParser`:

```py
def options(opt):
    opt.parser.remove_option("--top")
    opt.parser.remove_option("--no-msvs-lazy")
```

For commands, there is a metaclass in waf that automatically register Context classes (see [waflib.Context sources](https://waf.io/apidocs/_modules/waflib/Context.html#store_context)).

So all `Context` classes are stored in the global variable `waflib.Context.classes`. To get rid of them you can manipulate this variable. For instance to get rid of `StepContext` and such, you can do something like:

```py
import waflib

def options(opt):

    all_contexts = waflib.Context.classes

    all_contexts.remove(waflib.Build.StepContext)
    all_contexts.remove(waflib.Build.InstallContext)
    all_contexts.remove(waflib.Build.UninstallContext)
```

Commands `dist/distcheck` are special case defined in `waflib.Scripting`. It's not easy to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me to this [waf's apidocs](https://waf.io/apidocs/_modules/waflib/Tools/gnu_dirs.html) which solved my options problem. But for the `main` commands I could not follow your answer. Could you give me on that a more detailed answer please?